# Changing the UI with remoteservice.marshal

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, marshalling

The continuation of this theme WPF multithreading. Changing the interface of a third-party flow. Have not found the solution, not the problem dispatcher. Tell me how to properly interact with the remoteservice.marshal UI.

after changes have asked me to Samuel is not any mistakes there. But the interface is not updated.
we had a long correspondence with him but he could not help.